# LaTeX Error: Option clash for package geometry

Tags: geometry

I am doing my thesis and a colleague passed me the format with which I should write my thesis, but the moment to execute I get an error with the package geometry on line where it is written `\spacing{1.5}`. I do not know what to do.

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside ]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
%\spanishdecimal{.}%Para usar punto en vez de coma decimal
\usepackage{calligra} %tipo de letra
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}%centrar formulas
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}%Para poner fórmulas químicas
%\usepackage{graphicx} % figuras
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{booktabs} %Para tablas importadas de excel
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{colortbl}%row color
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} %Para dejar fija la tabla 
\usepackage{longtable} %Tabla en dos páginas
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{upgreek}%Para poner letras griegas en negrita
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras%Para imágenes seguidas
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{graphicx, wrapfig, setspace, booktabs}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}
\usepackage{setspace} %interlineados
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerados
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage[top=2.43cm,bottom=3cm,lmargin=3.21cm,rmargin=2.73cm,bindingoffset=0.25in,heightrounded,]{geometry}
\spacing{1.5} %**Here is the error that show me Texmaker**
\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont}{\vspace{-0.33cm}\filcenter \normalsize\textbf{CAPÍTULO \Roman{chapter}}}{2.2pt}{\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}
\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}
```

Comment: You load package `geometry` twice, with different options. That clashes. There is other stuff going on. You will get into more trouble with what he gave you. Bin it. See also [scientific reports](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Scientific_Reports).

Comment: `booktabs`, `emptypage`, `caption`, and `subfigure` are loaded twice, too, and `fancyhdr` is even loaded three times.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is deprecated; it shouldn't be used any longer. Use either `subfig` or `subcaption`. Since you load the `caption` package, I would guess that it's preferable to load `subcaption`. A separate comment: The `amsfonts` package is loaded automatically by the `amssymb` package -- no need to load it explicitly. Also, `hyperref` should be loaded *last* -- and certainly not multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like that you load every package which you aware of ... ;-)
The following should work:

```
\documentclass[12pt, oneside ]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{upgreek}%Para poner letras griegas en negrita
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}%Para poner fórmulas químicas
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{fourier}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage{calligra} %tipo de letra
\usepackage[protrusion=true, expansion=true]{microtype}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
%\spanishdecimal{.}%Para usar punto en vez de coma decimal

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{top=2.43cm,bottom=3cm,lmargin=3.21cm,
      rmargin=2.73cm,bindingoffset=0.25in,heightrounded}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsmath}%centrar formulas
\usepackage{graphicx} % figuras
\usepackage{subfigure} % subfiguras
\usepackage{booktabs} %Para tablas importadas de excel
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{float} %Para dejar fija la tabla 
\usepackage{longtable} %Tabla en dos páginas
\usepackage{stackrel}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{bigstrut}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage[myheadings]{fullpage}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[font=small, labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{titling}
\usepackage{enumerate} % enumerados
\usepackage{fancybox}
\usepackage{scrextend}
\usepackage{setspace} %interlineados
\onehalfspacing %**Here is the error that show me Texmaker**

%\usepackage{lastpage}

\titleformat{\chapter}[display]{\normalfont}{
  \vspace{-0.33cm}
  \filcenter \normalsize\textbf{CAPÍTULO \Roman{chapter}}}{2.2pt}{\normalsize\bfseries\filcenter}

\renewcommand{\thechapter}{\arabic{chapter}} 
\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{section}}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{equation}}
\renewcommand{\thefigure}{\arabic{figure}}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\pagenumbering{roman}

\begin{document}
    foo
\end{document}
```

Comment: OK, I've moved the comment to the query itself.